# Weird horizontal panning with IE 10 mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have made a collaborative writing website called Fablelane (https://www.fablelane.com).

It runs with a somewhat responsive layout (except it looks bad in mobile, but that is what I am working on). Now, if I visit the site in IE 10 mobile from my Nokia Lumia 920, I can pan about 20 pixels to the right.

I am pretty sure that I don't have any weird paddings anywhere and anything that creates unnecessary spacing. I also have the view port meta tag set correctly, and I have made everything box sized.

What am I doing wrong? The issue is hard to pinpoint for me since I don't have access to other smartphones than Windows Phones, and because it's not within my budget to buy things like BrowserStack. I haven't had luck setting up the local emulator to find my ASP .NET MVC localhost site either.

Can anyone help?

Comment: The chances are, something is extending out of its container and causing a horizontal scroll. Check to ensure that there is nothing that extends out of the flow of the document - you may need to play around with box-sizing and create a conditional for IE 10. Edit: I checked on a Windows Phone 8 with Windows Mobile 10 and see not horizontal scroll.

Comment: The scrollbar is not there, but after a full load it is possible to pan it (even though no scrollbars are visible).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is an overflow issue. Maybe try popping:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

into your css to see if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: Where in your CSS Did you add it?

Comment: In body, I specified `overflow-x: hidden;`

Comment: Just for fun, throw just "overflow:hidden;" in every section of CSS and not just body. If that resolves the problem then it has to be one of them.

Comment: I tried doing that. Almost every element had a scrollbar, and the elements turned invisible.

Comment: Did it get rid of the weird issue you were having though? Minus all of the new issues it introduced?

Comment: Nope. I'm afraid not.